# How to get Fantasy Grounds to account for encounter multipliers?

Tags: dnd-5e, tools, fantasy-grounds

I noticed that FG doesn't apply the multipliers in p. 82 of the DMG when designing an encounter—it simply adds up the XP totals for each NPC added. Is there a way to change this?

Comment: It may simply be that FG is calculating the encounter XP, not the XP-based difficulty of the encounter.  I don't know if there's a way to do that in FG.

Comment: That's what it's doing, which is lame (and not as useful as calculating encounter CR). Fortunately someone coded the extension posted in the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install [this extension](https://www.fantasygrounds.com/forums/showthread.php?26180-Posting-chat-message-only-to-myself&p=233194&viewfull=1#post233194) (copy to Application Data/FG/Extensions), which will not only calculate Encounter CR, but also tell you its difficulty (Easy-Deadly) based on the PCs (and their level) in the combat tracker.

Comment: that extension is discontinued, here's the updated link -> https://www.fantasygrounds.com/forums/showthread.php?33131-5E-Encounter-Calc